# How to assign value and type to the readonly fileds in typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, kendo-ui

I use kendo in angular2.x and in some case it contains somethings like this:

```
readonly className: true;
```

what is :true after filed-name? Is that type declaration(with true!! ops)??Is that assignment?
what is that?

Comment: are you sure that there is `:` points? Maybe it is `=` sign?

Comment: yes sure that is a real snippets of code

Comment: Could you add more code? E.g, class declaration and constructor, maybe some methods